# Java: Guessing game with randomized choice order

Tags: java, random, country

I'm trying to create a country quiz guessing game however, I have run into a problem. I want there to be a menu where a country is displayed and underneath there should be three capitals to choose from of which one is correct. The problem is I don't want the correct answer to be at the same position for every country, in other words I want the order of the alternatives to be randomized but, I'm not sure of how this could be done...

I have not come far with my code but here is my method:

```
  public static void gissaStadAlt(LandStad[] list) {

      for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which of the alternatives is the capital in " + list[i].land + "?" + "\n" +
                                       "1." + list[rand].stad + "\n" +
                                       "2." + list[i].stad + "\n" +
                                       "3." + list[rand].stad);
  }


}
```

I want the position of list[i].stad to be randomized

This is my LandStad class:

```
public class LandStad {

    String land;
    String stad;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have. Also can't you just use a random number generator

Comment: If you are using a list to hold your alternatives, you could simple call the shuffle method on the list.

Comment: Your code is not complete. What is `LandStad`? Where are the required imports? Where is your class declaration? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jubobs: I think - as a native speaker - land stad is Dutch for CountryCity. It is a quiz to guess the capital of countries.

Comment: @CommuSoft Thanks, but I wasn't asking what the word itself means. I just want to see the class definition, for completeness.

Comment: I'm sorry but, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just shuffle the array that you get? That way you can keep the JOptionPane dialogue the same, i.e.:

```
public static void gissaStadAlt(LandStad[] list) 
{
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(list));
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which of the alternatives is the 
                            capital in " + list.getLand() + "?" + "\n" +
                           "1." + list[0].city + "\n" +
                           "2." + list[1].city + "\n" +
                           "3." + list[2].city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
public static void gissaStadAlt(LandStad[] list) {

  for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      String[] options = new String[3];
      int rand = i;
      while(rand!=i){
          rand = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
      }
      options[0] = list[rand].city;
      int k = rand;
      while(rand!=i && rand!=k){
          rand = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
      }
      options[1] = list[rand].city;
      options[2] = list[i].city;
      int[] randomize = {123,132,213,231,312,321};
      int num = randomize[(int)(Math.random() * 6)];
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
          int g = num/100;
          options[i] = g + ". " + options[i];
          num%=100;
          num*=10;
      }
      Arrays.sort(options);
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which of the alternatives is the capital in " + list[i].land + "?" + "\n" +
                                   options[0] + "\n" +
                                   options[1] + "\n" +
                                   options[2]);
```

}